# Is there any way to connect printer from Android phones through wifi for printing?

Tags: android, printing, android-wifi

I would like to print from Android phone to printer through wifi.Is there any chance of doing it.Because I tried searching around and ended up with only apps being available.Any sample codes to do this are available means please share or also provide your expertise on this.Thank you.